# What is $P(A\mid B)(C\mid D)$? Is this the same as $P(A\mid B) \times P(C\mid D)$?

Tags: probability, notation

I'm curious about the general case but also need to understand if $P(A|B)(C|D)$ is the same as $P(A|B) \times P(C|D).$

In equation (7), it states

[image]

Is this the same as $P(u|f,s) \times P(f|s)$ ?

[image: Example Usage]

The article is available at https://mechanicaldesign.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=2297650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. I think there is a typo in the original source. In general it holds that
\begin{equation}
p(x,y|z) =  p(x|y,z) p(y|z)
\end{equation}
and therefore,
\begin{equation}
p(x|z) = \sum_y p(x,y|z) = \sum_y p(x|y,z) p(y|z)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for helping.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if you found it helpful.